# How to enumerate on series on dygraphs?

Tags: dygraphs

I need to change some series axis to `y2` in `dygraphs`. The ones that need to change are dynamic and so I don't know which on will be. And `.attributes_.series_` isn't enumerable .Anybody knows how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

dygraphs currently has an [issue](https://github.com/danvk/dygraphs/issues/629) with moving a series from one axis to another. To work around this, you'll have to re-create the chart by calling `new Dygraph` again:

```
g = new Dygraph(div, data, {
      series: {
        YourSeries: {
          axis: 'y2'
        }
      }
    });
```

Here's a fully-worked [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/0h1z72s0/1746/).